Trouble setting up gulpfile.js using ES module
I am trying to set up my Gulp workflow using the latest versions of all packages. I am used to CommonJS and having some difficulty figuring out how to get my tasks to run. I have a task to compile sass/js and a watch task. In my package.json I added "type": "module" but when I try to run my watch task I am getting
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope

Here is what my gulpfile looks like:
import gulp from 'gulp';
const { src, dest, watch, series } = gulp;
import * as dartSass from 'sass';
import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';
const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);
import prefix from 'gulp-autoprefixer';
import minify from 'gulp-clean-css';

// SCSS
function compilescss() {
    return src('src/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(prefix('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(dest('/dist/css'))
}


// JS
function jsmin(){
    return src('src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(terser())
        .pipe(dest('dist/js'))
}

// create watchlist
function watchTask(){
    watch('src/scss/*.scss', compilescss);
    watch('src/js/*.js', jsmin);
}

// default gulp
exports.default = series(
    compilescss,
    jsmin,
    watchTask
);

